# SWT Text fails to compute correct width if text contains tab ie '\t'

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

Please refer following snippet
Correct width is not displayed

```
Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell( display );
        Text helloWorldTest = new Text( shell, SWT.BORDER |SWT.READ_ONLY);
        helloWorldTest.setText( "A\tB");
        helloWorldTest.pack();
        shell.pack(); //optional
        shell.open();
        while( !shell.isDisposed() )
        {
            if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
```

Here, I want to use text with editable false. I also want to show context menus so can not use label.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `GC.textExtent(String string)`...

Comment: I used StyledText which supports this case.